# Viewflipper is fixed at top, not hides on scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, viewflipper

I have this app to show news article.

I wanted to add an auto image slider so I use `viewflipper`. And below that I have a `recycler view`.

When I scroll `recycler view`, new views come but `viewflipper` is still fixed on the top.

Comment: Add some code so we can see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

just scroll the viewflipper with the position of recyclerview position

Comment: if you scroll the recycle view then get the scrolled position and scroll view flipper with this position